# How do I merge two dataframes that don't share one common index?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Here is the first DataFrame:

```
In: df.head()
Out:
                                      avg_lmp  avg_load
read_year read_month trading_block                     
2017      3          0              24.606666  0.018033
                     1              32.090800  0.023771
          4          0              25.136200  0.017487
                     1              33.487529  0.023570
          5          0              24.085170  0.018008
```

And here is the second DataFrame that I want to join to the first one based on month (even if it has to repeat values such as `read_year = 2018` and `read_month = 3`. If it's 2019 and the `read_month` is 3, I want it to say the same value for `read_month` 3.

```
In: df2.head()
Out:
                                fpc
read_month trading_block           
1          0              37.501837
           1              45.750000
2          0              35.531818
           1              41.550000
3          0              28.348427
           1              35.900000
4          0              26.250870
           1              34.150000
5          0              23.599388
           1              34.550000
6          0              25.617027
           1              38.670000
7          0              27.531765
           1              42.050000
8          0              26.628298
           1              40.400000
9          0              25.201923
           1              36.500000
10         0              25.299149
           1              35.250000
11         0              25.349091
           1              34.300000
12         0              28.249623
           1              35.500000
```

Is it clear what I'm asking for?

Comment: Not 100% clear. It would help if you could show an example of how the DataFrame you're after looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have common indexes. Set them, then join:

```
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['read_month', 'trading_block']).join(df2)
```

and if you wish:

```
df.reset_index().set_index(['read year', 'read_month', 'trading_block'])
```

Not sure if that is what you're after:

```
                                    index    avg_lmp  avg_load        fpc
read_year read_month trading_block                                       
2017      3          0                  0  24.606666  0.018033  28.348427
                     1                  1  32.090800  0.023771  35.900000
          4          0                  2  25.136200  0.017487  26.250870
                     1                  3  33.487529  0.023570  34.150000
          5          0                  4  24.085170  0.018008  23.599388
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this. just merge on the two columns with a outer. (like full outer)
    DataFrame1.merge(DataFrame2, left_on='read_month', right_on='read_month', how='outer')

Comment: Did you write that out correctly? You put 2 `read_month` in there.